# CryptoJS getting Sha256 hash as UTF-8 string

Tags: react-native, cryptography, cryptojs

Im using crypto-js for doing hashing in React Native.

I have some piece of code using a different library which can sign strings or binary data using Ed25519 keys.

I am trying to get the `crypto-js` SHA256 hash converted to a `UTF-8` string so I can use it with the library. But, it keeps saying `Malformed UTF-8 data`

I am not sure if I can't convert it to UTF-8 at all? Which is weird because I've been able to do it using Node's crypto module successfully - just unable to do it using `crypto-js`

Here's my code: https://repl.it/repls/CornsilkPlasticSpof

Also, adding here to prevent link death,

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const dataToBeHashed = "testing";

const toBeSigned = CryptoJS.SHA256(dataToBeHashed).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(toBeSigned);
```

This gives

```
Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
    at Object.stringify (/home/runner/CornsilkPlasticSpof/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:513:24)
    at WordArray.init.toString (/home/runner/CornsilkPlasticSpof/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:268:38)
    at /home/runner/CornsilkPlasticSpof/index.js:5:52
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:131:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:156:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:
```

Answer (score 2):

A hash is effectively random bytes.  Those random bytes are very unlikely to be well-formed UTF-8 characters.  What you need to do is to convert your bytes to Base64 which will be in UTF-8.